# Django URL invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django

I have a Location model setup in Django and I originally set it up so that the URL was /location/3/ using the primary key. but the client want to change it to use a slug of the location name. I created a slug field in the model. And changed the URL pattern in urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.LocationsSingleView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

I can link to them fine. But when it tries to actually load that page I get an error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'eau-claire'

Where eau-claire is the slug for that Location.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) doesn't say anything about this.

A lot of people with this issue have issues with their view. But my view is super simple. So I don't know what's wrong. Here is my view:

```
class LocationsSingleView(DetailView):
    model = models.Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `slug` instead of `pk` in the URL pattern to tell Django you want to look up by the slug.

Comment: Additional: `pk` means primary key.

Comment: Weird. I did that and I swear it didn't work before. So I reverted back to using pk because in a separate template, using href="{% url 'detail' slug=location.slug %}" is messy to me. But okay thank you.